# Use Oauth2 token in my classview to allow some user access only his own user data?

Tags: django, authentication, oauth, restrict

I use a token to retrieve user data in a mobile App. But...if a user has authenticated can access the data of another users....How I restrict that only the own user token access to the own user data in the model Users? (Sorry my bad english)

Comment: Please provide minimal code example and be more specific describing the problem

Answer (score 0):

I use this for retrieve user info...now I`m using IsAuthenticated with a valid oauth2 token in permission_classes, but I would like that only the user of that valid token can access to the UserDetail viewset

```
class UserDetail(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    lookup_field = 'username' 
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

```
class Prueba(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = User.objects.all().filter(username=self.request.user)
        return queryset
```